# Nginx not displaying ServerBlocks

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, server

I'm working on a mac, using VirtualBox and Ubuntu server 20.04 using a Bridged Connection. I have set up the Nginx server and the default page is loading. I was able to edit /var/www/html/index.html to say hello world.
I can view this default page by visiting http://ip/.

The server blocks files in /var/www/ are named 'html' (the default), 'site1' and 'site2'
All the 'site' maps have a html map inside of them, containing index.html with some HelloWorld text inside of them.

All the above code/info should be correct.  Therefore, I assume that the error is in the configuration.

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled contain 3 files. 'default', 'site1' and 'site2'. I will show the 'default' file and the 'site1' file in the code below.

Going to http://site1/ results in an error page, chrome displays an IP error instead of the index.html file.

Could someone show me what I'm doing wrong?

Site1 file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/site1/html;
    index index.html index htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name site1 www.site1;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

Default file:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
```

}

Comment: http://192.168.178.52/ is your private ip. No one can use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `server_name site1 www.site1;` is wrong because there are not any local domain names like `site1` or `www.site1` that configured in your computer to route to `127.0.0.1`.

So you need to config a local domain on your computer so whenever you browse `site1` or `www.site1` they will be routed to `127.0.0.1`. On ubuntu, just change the `/etc/hosts` file to sth like this:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   site1
127.0.1.1   www.site1
```

However im not sure how to make samething done on MacOS  because i have never use mac lol. But I found a link that might help you :

https://markinns.com/archive/how-to-setup-a-local-dns-host-file-on-mac-os-x.html